# How to download content of a webpage URL as pdf in JavaScript without opening the link?

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs3, pdf-generation, quasar-framework

I have a download profile button on a different page, if I click on that button, it has to download my profile page content as PDF, particularly the content of the class name '.resume'. I have implemented same page download option using html2pdf library, but clueless about how to download from a different page. Please help me in this, thank you.

Same Page Download Code:

```
const downloadPDF = async () => {
    
      const resume = document.querySelector('.resume');
      toHide.value = 'none'
    
      await html2pdf()
        .set({filename: 'resume.pdf'})
        .from(resume)
        .save()
    
      toHide.value = 'inline'
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the same origin, you can [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the page and extract the resume

Something like this

[Working example](https://plungjan.name/SO/dlresume/)

```js
const downloadPDF = async() => {
  // Fetch the HTML content of the resume page
  fetch('resume.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(htmlContent => {
      // Create a temporary div (fragment) to hold the HTML content
      const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
      tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
      // Extract the resume element
      const resume = tempDiv.querySelector('.resume');
      toHide.value = 'none'; // not sure what that is, you did not elaborate
      // Generate PDF
      return html2pdf()
        .set({
          filename: 'resume.pdf'
        })
        .from(resume)
        .save();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Something went wrong: ", error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // Restore the state if necessary? If the div is not needed, drop it
      toHide.value = 'inline';
    });
};
```

Comment: ChatGPT suggested almost the same code, but unfortunately both codes not working.

Comment: The code I wrote works. I do not know what to do with `tohide` so I commented it out.

Comment: For your code, I am getting error: `Something went wrong:  Error: Unknown source type.` I modified according to my requirement, fetch url is `http://localhost:9000/#/employer/view-intern-profile/${applicant.internship}/${applicant.applicant}`

Comment: I got the same when I did not specify a correct file name. It cannot find the file. Use relative addressing. Add a console.log: `.then(htmlContent => { console.log(htmlContent);`